# React.jsx: type is invalid when testing a React component with an svg with Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: typescript, svg, jestjs, next.js

I have a Next.js 12.1.4 project using Typescript, React Testing Library and SVGR for importing icons like this: `import ChevronLeftIcon from './chevron-left.svg'`

The issue I have is that when I run a test of a component that include an SVG import, I get the following error:

```
console.error
    Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    
    Check the render method of `Loader`.
        at Loader (.../src/components/atoms/Loader/Loader.tsx:11:36)
        at div
        at button
        at Button (.../src/components/atoms/buttons/Button/Button.tsx:19:5)

      15 |         }`}
      16 |     >
    > 17 |         <LoaderIcon />
         |                       ^
      18 |     </div>
      19 | )
      20 |

      at printWarning (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:117:30)
      at error (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:93:5)
      at jsxWithValidation (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1152:7)
      at Object.jsxWithValidationDynamic [as jsx] (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1209:12)
      at Loader (src/components/atoms/Loader/Loader.tsx:17:23)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811:13)
```

I run tests with `yarn test` which matches the following `script` from my `package.json`:
`"test": "TZ=UTC ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",`

Here is what I have in `next.config.js` for SVGR:

```
webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })

    return config
},
```

Here is my jest.config.js:

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
})

const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/svgrMock.tsx',
  },
}

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

and `src/__mocks__/svgrMock.tsx`

```
import React, { SVGProps } from 'react'

const SvgrMock = React.forwardRef<SVGSVGElement, SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>(
    (props, ref) => <svg ref={ref} {...props} />,
)

SvgrMock.displayName = 'SvgrMock'

export const ReactComponent = SvgrMock
export default SvgrMock
```

I also tried to use `jest-svg-transformer` without much success.

Here are the versions of the libraries involved:

- "next": "^12.1.4"
- "react": "17.0.2"
- "react-dom": "17.0.2"
- "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0"
- "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4"
- "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4"
- "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.0.4"
- "jest": "^27.5.1"
- "ts-jest": "^27.1.3"
- "typescript": "4.4.4"

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You are missing an svg-loader/file-loader in your webpack configuration. What you are using (`@svgo/webpack`) is only an optimizer for your SVG's but it is not something that converts the SVG into an JSX file or a file path.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Would you be able to give me a webpack configuration example I could use?

Comment: Have a look at the README of the `file-loader` for example: https://webpack-v3.jsx.app/loaders/file-loader/

Answer (score 6):

After a few days of trials and errors, I was able to fix this issue by using the Jest with Babel configuration from the `Next.js` documentation, instead of using the `next/jest` plugin powered by the Rust compiler:  https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-babel

I also had to defined a jest transformer for the svg files, `jestSvgTransformer.js`:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  process(src, filePath) {
    if (path.extname(filePath) !== '.svg') {
      return src
    }

    const name = `svg-${path.basename(filePath, '.svg')}`
      .split(/\W+/)
      .map((x) => `${x.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${x.slice(1)}`)
      .join('')

    return `
const React = require('react');
function ${name}(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'svg',
    Object.assign({}, props, {'data-file-name': ${name}.name})
  )
}
module.exports = ${name}
            `
  },
}
```

In `jest.config.js`

- in `moduleNameMapper`: remove `svg` from the `'^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp)$/i': '<rootDir>/<path to your mock files (e.g.) __mocks__>/fileMock.js',`
- in `transform`: add `'^.+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/<path to your mock files (e.g.) __mocks__>/jestSvgTransformer.js'`
- add `moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],` to enable absolute imports